# Spline chart rounded edges

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way of rounding both edges of the spline chart? I am almost sure I saw it done before but can't find it in the API docs.

Now my chart looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantely this option is not avaiable, but you can try to modify i.e SVG element (series).

Comment: could you please point out some references how to style it using SVG element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linecap`, which defaults to `round` in the current Highcharts version.

```
plotOptions: {
    spline: {
        linecap: 'round'
    }
}
```

As far as I know, the only two options are `round` (default) and `square`.

Official docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.spline.linecap